# How to use List<model> by reference not by value?

Tags: c#, list, model-binding

OK.  I have State which has List.  I want to have multiple instances of State that use the same list of Series.

```
public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Series> Serieses { get; set; }
}

public class Series
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

After Creating a State by typing in the Name of the State and selecting 1 or more Series from a ListBox:

```
public ActionResult Create(State state, FormCollection form)
    {

      // method to get selected Series from db

      foreach (var sItem in seriesModel//List of Possible Series)
      {
          foreach (var item in Selections//User selected Series)
          {

             if (sItem.Name == item.Name)
             {
                newSeries.Add(sItem);
             }
          }
      }

      state.Serieses = newSeries;
      _db.Entry(state).State = EntityState.Modified;
      _db.SaveChanges();
```

The problem is after I create one instance of State with List. If I create a second instance and use the same Series in its list, the first will lose that Series in its list.  So obviously Series is being passed by value and not reference.  I'm new to C#, but back in C++ we would use pointers.  That way if I change the original values of Series it will show up on each State list that points to it.  I've also noticed in the Table Data in the Database, it has added a Foreign Key State_Id to every Series.  Here's the Table Definition it created when I used Code First method.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Series] (
[Id]       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Name]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
[State_Id] INT            NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Series] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Series_dbo.States_State_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([State_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[States] ([Id])
```

Comment: Is ModelA suppose to be State and ModelB suppose to be Series?

Comment: Yes.  A State has a list of multiple Series that can also be used by other States.

Comment: I dont understand why you lose Series from the list. Also have you thought about using `struct` instead of `class` for Series.

Comment: Can you add an example of how you create the second state and assign `Series` to it?  Classes are reference types in the .NET framework, so if you have two classes (say A and B), and you set A = B, they will both point to the same address, and any changes to one class will reflect in the other.

Comment: When a State is created, you add the Name and then you choose from a list of Series.  You can choose 1 or more series to add to it.  Then I use the for loop above to match those selections to possible Series.  If they match they are added to the List in State.

Comment: Explain why do you want `Serieses` to be `virtual`?

Comment: If I don't use virtual, it doesn't load up the Collection of Series.  I believe I've found the problem, the foreign key.

Comment: I think a bit of the confusion here is that this question doesn't mention Entity Framework (EF) Code First anywhere in the title or tags. Better answers would have been forthcoming with that. I'd suggest updating if you can so others with this problem will be able to find the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Entity Framework with Code First you will have to add a collection of States to your series as well in order to generate a many-to-many relationship table.

```
public class Series
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; set; } 
}
```

You will have to run a code first data migration as well using the package manager console.

```
Add-Migration <YourMigrationNameHere>
```

Resulting in the following DB structure after you run your app next:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As quoted [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx), "The **ref** keyword causes an argument to be passed by reference, not by value."

An ugly way to use this would be something like the following, since you can't change the declaration of `value`:

```
public MyClass {
    private string myString;

    public void SetMyString(ref string str) {
        myString = str
    }
}
```

I don't really suggest this though.

Answer (score 0):

How about making it static?

```
public static ICollection<Series> Serieses { get; set; }
```

Comment: @RichardReniewicki Of course there is. You can't just change it to static and expect it to automagically be fine.

Comment: I know, but errors that I would have to change the entire project to fix. And still didn't fix my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not looking to alter the list differently for each instance, use a static list. You can just access it like this.

```
State.Serieses
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `AddRange()` method

```
//replace 'state.Serieses = newSeries;' with
state.Serieses.AddRange(newSeries);
```

Make sure in the constructor for state than you initialize `Serieses` with a new empty series.

BTW Serieses is not word. The plural of *Series* is *Series*.

**Update**

I don't know why you need interfaces for the collections and cannot just use `List<Series>`. That part has not been explained. Also why `virtual`?

Here is skeleton code on how to keep the same collection and use `AddRange()`

```
// StackOverflow 16764155
public class Series
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class State
{
    public State()
    {
        Serieses = new List<Series>();
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Series> Serieses { get; set; }
}

public class DbForm
{
    public IEnumerable<Series> Selection { get; }
}

public class DbLogic
{

    public void Create(State state, IEnumerable<Series> selection)
    {
        state.Serieses.AddRange(selection);

        // do db stuff
        // _db.Entry(state).State = EntityState.Modified;
        // _db.SaveChanges();
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var form = new DbForm();
        var state = new State();
        var db = new DbLogic();
        // stuff here
        var sel = form.Selection;
        db.Create(state, sel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know Serieses is not a word, I was trying to differentiate between the two.

Comment: I also tried using AddRange(), it didn't like it.  Say I'm missing a using directive and won't give me a way to add one.

Comment: Microsoft has used `SeriesCollection` to differentiate in the past.